# How can I modify the folder name inside the zip downloaded from my github repo?

Tags: github

The folder name of the zip downloaded from github is like `%repository-name%-master`, but I need that folder just as `%repository-name%`

Can this be done?

Comment: Why don't you do a shallow clone instead? `git clone --depth=1 repo_url repository-name`

Comment: Is this a question about github? Or do you just want to use a tool to modify (the folder name inside) the downloaded zip file?

Comment: @nhahtdh: Its about github

Comment: I don't think there is anyway to do that.

Comment: Maybe in stead of calling my project something like "settings-manager" I will call it "settings" and in the documentation I will call it "settings-master".  Seriously this is irksome

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify the name of the root directory contained in an archive from github.

Even when you download master:

```
wget https://github.com/user/repo/tarball/master
```

You will get a file named 'master', but:

```
tar xpvf master
```

The `tar xpvf` will give you a `repo-xxxx` directory.
I usually follow with:

```
mv repo-* repo
```